# Rails include relation model into model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class Something
  belongs_to :User
end

class User
  has_many :something
end
```

I can call Something.all and get the object array

```
[#<Something:0x0000558f81437158
  id: "c2c0506e-57db-4d39-8f5b-20fde15aa1a4",
  user_id:"XXX-XXX">]
```

When I use `Something.includes(:user)` I get the exact same result.
I was under the impression that I get some included user object inside my something object.
When I use for example `Something.all.as_json(includes: :user)` I get a merged json hash. Issue is I don't want a merged json hash. Is there something wrong somewhere in my models or how does `.includes` work?

Usecase would be my index action that responses automatically with json and I just need to build the correct object hash without writing as_json all over the place.

Anyone?

Comment: You need to use gem 'active_model_serializers'

Comment: I did not get what do you want to achieve?

Comment: `Something.includes(:user).references(:user)` will eager load the `User` for `Something` and you can access it via the instance method `user` without executing a new query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following gem to your Gemfile

```
gem 'active_model_serializers'
```

Then install it using bundle

```
bundle install
```

You can generate a serializer as follows

```
rails g serializer something
rails g serializer user
```

it will create Serializer class file in

```
# app/serializers/something_serializer.rb

    class SomethingSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
       attributes :id, 

       has_many :users 
    end

# app/serializers/user_serializer.rb
   class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
       attributes :id, :name
    end
```

In controller

```
def index
  @something = Something.includes(:users).all


  render json: @something
end
```